# запись soundpool

Tags: java, android, аудио, record

В моём приложении на android я использую воспроизведение 12-ти звуков с помощью класса soundpool,теперь у меня возник вопрос,есть ли какой нибудь метод записи в аудио файл при проигрывании этих файлов?